# Running a jQuery Function using a button inside fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox loading on a page that has an animated multistep form.

The fancybox consists of several link one of which is supposed to trigger the form after closing fancybox.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();" id="startbox">
<img src="http://website.com/img/button.png"><br>Fill the form</a>
```

I read about the afterClose function in Fancybox and tried implementing it by adding this

```
$(" #startbox").fancybox({
 afterClose: function() {
$('#main').addClass('fadeOutLeft').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#step1').addClass('fadeInRight active-step').show();
}
});
```

I am using the above for a button on the page itself and it works perfectly. Essentially fading out the current setup and fading in the form step 1 - below code for your reference

```
$('#start').click(function() {
  $('#main').addClass('fadeOutLeft').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#step').addClass('fadeInRight active-step').show();
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I am stumped. The fancybox closes and that's it.

Comment: Would you mind to add this in jsfiddle? I'm not sure what's really problem even this afterClose worked perfect.

Comment: Looks like a typo: in the click function you're using `$('#step')` instead of `$('#step1')`

Comment: @Ivan Not sure how do I add this into a fiddle, there is a lot of code happening. HTML + CSS + the fading animation.

Comment: @Meldon It was a typo here, I was changing the name of the steps.

Comment: JSfiddle is an online debug tool where we can study then solve the problem http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `afterClose` should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vommx731/